# Deserialize String to Google TokenResponse

Tags: c#, google-api, json.net, google-api-dotnet-client

I'm writing a little application which has to authenticate users with google and get their calendars.

If a User accept the request, Google gives us a RequestToken which has a RefreshToken.
We store the RefreshToken in our Database with the Example from [Diamto DatabaseDataStore](https://github.com/LindaLawton/Google-Dotnet-Samples/blob/master/Authentication/Diamto.Google.Authentication/Diamto.Google.Authentication/DatabaseDataStore.cs).

To Store the RefreshToken in the database I do this:

```
var serialized = NewtonsoftJsonSerializer.Instance.Serialize(value);
```

Alright. It works fine, but when I'm looking for the RefreshToken in the database it has to get deserialized. For this I use that

```
TaskCompletionSource<T> tcs = new TaskCompletionSource<T>();
....
tcs.SetResult(NewtonsoftJsonSerializer.Instance.Deserialize<T>(refreshToken));
```

RefreshToken is a String from the Database.

On the deserialization, i get following error:

> Could not cast or convert from System.String to
>   Google.Apis.Auth.OAuth2.Responses.TokenResponse.

I hope, anyone can tell me where the problem is.

Comment: I think I had this problem as well, but its been a while.   I seam to remember having a version some place where I just dumped the full response back from Google into the database.  It made it easer to parse it back into the DataStore.   I will see what I can find on my laptop when I get home.

Comment: Thanks for your response @DaImTo. I hope you will find something.
Do you mean, we should just send it into the database without serializing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you can just create a new instance of TokenResponse with the new string, as following:

```
var tokenResponse = new TokenResponse
{
    RefreshToken = refreshToken // or you will have to deserialize the string first
}
```

Then you can continue to use the library as it is, the token response doesn't have an access token, so the library will try to refresh your access token using refresh token you just got from your database.

TokenResponse code is available at:
https://github.com/google/google-api-dotnet-client/blob/master/Src/GoogleApis.Auth/OAuth2/Responses/TokenResponse.cs#L49

The code that will reuse the token response is available here:
https://github.com/google/google-api-dotnet-client/blob/master/Src/GoogleApis.Auth/OAuth2/AuthorizationCodeInstalledApp.cs#L67